# Docker Ubuntu 20.04 - Cannot uninstall 'terminado' and problems with pip

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pip, ubuntu-20.04

I'am trying to reproduce the Docker Installation of the Book ["Mining the Social Web" (Russel/Klassen)](https://github.com/mikhailklassen/Mining-the-Social-Web-3rd-Edition) on Ubuntu 20.04. I set up Docker and tried to create the Docker container from the respository directly (repo2docker https://github.com/mikhailklassen/Mining-the-Social-Web-3rd-Edition) for opening the Jupyter Notebook, but I got ERRORS. Before I installed Python3 and pip3 (couldn't install just Python and pip).

Got this multiple inside the running code:

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
```

(cannot fix the problem with the link inside)

and this ERROR at the End of Code:

```
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'terminado'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
Removing intermediate container 71cfe8e913dd
The command '/bin/sh -c ${KERNEL_PYTHON_PREFIX}/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir -r "binder/requirements.txt"' returned a non-zero code:1
```

Maybe somebody can help me? thx a lot!

Comment: On which command where did you get this error?

Comment: After running docker and puting in the command:

repo2docker https://github.com/mikhailklassen/Mining-the-Social-Web-3rd-Edition

Comment: Make sure you install it using `pip3 install jupyter-repo2docker`?

Comment: It's unable to uninstall tornado==6.0.2 which is specified in [binder/requirements.tx](https://github.com/mikhailklassen/Mining-the-Social-Web-3rd-Edition/blob/master/binder/requirements.txt).

First try to uninstall through: `pip uninstall tornado`
If it doesn't works, try to remove it manually from site-packages.

If none works, my recommendation would be to create a virtualenv and do the Python installation step inside virtualenv, basically the  'POST Docker' step.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!

@Turan Lalwani: 

`pip3 install jupyter-repo2docker` seems to work, but I got the same Warning inside the code 

`WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.`

Comment: @Saurabh

`pip uninstall tornado` seems to work in the first moment:

`ubu20_admin@News3819:~$ pip3 uninstall tornado
Found existing installation: tornado 6.0.4
Uninstalling tornado-6.0.4:
  Would remove:
    /home/ubu20_admin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado-6.0.4.dist-info/*
    /home/ubu20_admin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled tornado-6.0.4`

Comment: but finally I got at the end of code:

`ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'terminado'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`


I just want to open the jupyter notebook from
`repo2docker https://github.com/mikhailklassen/Mining-the-Social-Web-3rd-Edition`

Is there another way too or does this mean, that I cannot use Docker in the right way via Terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to your issue, don't use docker as it won't be able to uninstall the tornado package which is a pure distutil package due to pip install instructions. Use below solution:

I work on virtual envs, and would recommend you to do the same.

> Clone the repo
>
> navigate to /binder
>
> execute `pip install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt`
>
> navigate to /notebooks
>   Execute `jupyter notebook`

Comment: For this: execute `pip install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt` I got: 

`Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden: 'requirements.txt'`

Comment: For navigate to /notebooks Execute `jupyter notebook` I got:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubu20_admin/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/home/ubu20_admin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .nbextensions import install_nbextension`

Comment: `File "/home/ubu20_admin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 605, in <module>
    from .extensions import (
  File "/home/ubu20_admin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/extensions.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tornado.log import LogFormatter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado'`

Comment: didn't know what exactly I had done, but now it works and I can open the jupyter notebook from terminal (I guess I just installed tornado with  `pip3 install tornado --user --ignore-installed`

Comment: Good to know :)

Comment: Can you mark this as answered if it has solved your query? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67134670/1290868

For me it was this line in requirements.txt;

```
...
jupyterlab>=1.0
....
```

removed the version part (">=1.0") and it worked;

```
...
jupyterlab
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I was tying to update jupyter notebook / jupyterlab and had issues with terminado, not sure what it is. Even after uninstalling it, it was avl (not sure why).
Hence, I uninstalled jupyterlab and installed it back again.