# Kedro install - Cannot uninstall `terminado`

Tags: python, pip, kedro

When running `kedro install` I get the following error:

```sh
Attempting uninstall: terminado
    Found existing installation: terminado 0.8.3
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'terminado'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

This github [issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4543) suggests the following fix:

```sh
pip install terminado --user --ignore-installed
```

But it does not work for me as I keep having the same error.

**Note:**
This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61770369/docker-ubuntu-20-04-cannot-uninstall-terminado-and-problems-with-pip) but different enough that I think it is worth asking separately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is the version that the kedro template project requires see `src/requiremetns.txt`

In my project it is `terminado==0.9.1`, hence the following solves the problem:

```sh
pip install terminado==0.9.1  --user --ignore-installed
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was this line in requirements.txt;

```
...
jupyterlab>=1.0
....
```

removed the version part (">=1.0") and it worked;

```
...
jupyterlab
....
```